Use R ggplot to with geom point and line grouped by MULITPLE conditions
I am trying to connect points of each Genotype per Treatment with a line but I have grouped the points by multiple conditions. Below my code so far:
ggplot(ResponseData, 
         aes(x = Time , y = ETR , group = Genotype, color = Treatment, shape=Genotype)) +
    geom_point(size=c(2)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = Treatment)) +  
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(19,24)) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,61), ylim = c(0,200)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position="right")

I can achieve lines connected by treatment, but I would like to connect them by treatment AND Genotype. Below shows the figure I can create but the lines connect the wrong points. I would like the line connecting e.g. all triangles of the red color treatment (like I added manually in the figure) over time for each set of points. How can I achieve this?
I have already tried using:
geom_pathand
geom_line(group = interaction("Genotype", "Treatment"))
but this did not produce any lines for me.
Is there anyone of you who could help me out? I'd appreciate it a lot!
Here my data as requested:
dput(head(ResponseData,30))
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Control", "Drought", 
"Heat", "HeatDrought"), class = "factor"), Time = c(5.58333333333333, 
10.5833333333333, 15.5833333333333, 20.5833333333333, 25.5833333333334, 
30.5833333333334, 35.5833333333334, 40.5833333333333, 47.4583333333332, 
52.8333333333332, 57.8333333333331, 61.9166666666664, 5.58333333333333, 
10.5833333333333, 15.5833333333333, 20.5833333333333, 25.5833333333334, 
30.5833333333334, 35.5833333333334, 40.5833333333333, 47.4583333333332, 
52.8333333333332, 57.8333333333331, 61.9166666666664, 5.58333333333333, 
10.5833333333333, 15.5833333333333, 20.5833333333333, 25.5833333333334, 
30.5833333333334), Genotype = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("KU15", "KU2"
), class = "factor"), ETR = c(118.796666666667, 132.66, 136.46, 
140.026666666667, 138.51, 140.056666666667, 27.0666666666667, 
27.9566666666667, 28.3933333333333, 28.72, 29.03, 29.1066666666667, 
118.383333333333, 139.48, 144.196666666667, 146.816666666667, 
149.303333333333, 149.93, 27.64, 28.6, 29.0066666666667, 29.39, 
29.51, 29.76, 56.615, 63.075, 67.6875, 71.0575, 71.6125, 75.1275
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 2L, `3` = 3L, `4` = 4L, 
`5` = 5L, `7` = 7L, `8` = 8L, `9` = 9L, `10` = 10L, `12` = 12L, 
`13` = 13L, `14` = 14L, `15` = 15L, `17` = 17L, `18` = 18L, `19` = 19L, 
`20` = 20L, `22` = 22L, `23` = 23L, `24` = 24L, `25` = 25L, `27` = 27L, 
`28` = 28L, `29` = 29L, `30` = 30L, `32` = 32L, `33` = 33L, `34` = 34L, 
`35` = 35L, `37` = 37L, `38` = 38L, `39` = 39L, `40` = 40L, `42` = 42L, 
`43` = 43L, `44` = 44L, `45` = 45L, `47` = 47L, `48` = 48L, `49` = 49L, 
`50` = 50L, `52` = 52L, `53` = 53L, `54` = 54L, `55` = 55L, `57` = 57L, 
`58` = 58L, `59` = 59L, `61` = 61L, `62` = 62L, `63` = 63L, `64` = 64L, 
`65` = 65L, `67` = 67L, `68` = 68L, `69` = 69L, `70` = 70L, `72` = 72L, 
`73` = 73L, `74` = 74L, `75` = 75L, `77` = 77L, `78` = 78L, `79` = 79L, 
`80` = 80L, `82` = 82L, `83` = 83L, `84` = 84L, `85` = 85L, `87` = 87L, 
`88` = 88L, `89` = 89L, `90` = 90L, `92` = 92L, `93` = 93L, `94` = 94L, 
`95` = 95L, `97` = 97L, `98` = 98L, `99` = 99L, `100` = 100L, 
`102` = 102L, `103` = 103L, `104` = 104L, `105` = 105L, `107` = 107L, 
`108` = 108L, `109` = 109L, `110` = 110L, `112` = 112L, `113` = 113L, 
`114` = 114L, `115` = 115L, `117` = 117L, `118` = 118L, `119` = 119L, 
`121` = 121L, `122` = 122L, `123` = 123L, `124` = 124L, `125` = 125L, 
`127` = 127L, `128` = 128L, `129` = 129L, `130` = 130L, `132` = 132L, 
`133` = 133L, `134` = 134L, `135` = 135L, `137` = 137L, `138` = 138L, 
`139` = 139L, `140` = 140L, `142` = 142L, `143` = 143L, `144` = 144L, 
`145` = 145L, `147` = 147L, `148` = 148L, `149` = 149L, `150` = 150L, 
`152` = 152L, `153` = 153L, `154` = 154L, `155` = 155L, `157` = 157L, 
`158` = 158L, `159` = 159L, `160` = 160L, `162` = 162L, `163` = 163L, 
`164` = 164L, `165` = 165L, `167` = 167L, `168` = 168L, `169` = 169L, 
`170` = 170L, `172` = 172L, `173` = 173L, `174` = 174L, `175` = 175L, 
`177` = 177L, `178` = 178L, `179` = 179L, `181` = 181L, `182` = 182L, 
`183` = 183L, `184` = 184L, `185` = 185L, `187` = 187L, `188` = 188L, 
`189` = 189L, `190` = 190L, `192` = 192L, `193` = 193L, `194` = 194L, 
`195` = 195L, `197` = 197L, `198` = 198L, `199` = 199L, `200` = 200L, 
`202` = 202L, `203` = 203L, `204` = 204L, `205` = 205L, `207` = 207L, 
`208` = 208L, `209` = 209L, `210` = 210L, `212` = 212L, `213` = 213L, 
`214` = 214L, `215` = 215L, `217` = 217L, `218` = 218L, `219` = 219L, 
`220` = 220L, `222` = 222L, `223` = 223L, `224` = 224L, `225` = 225L, 
`227` = 227L, `228` = 228L, `229` = 229L, `230` = 230L, `232` = 232L, 
`233` = 233L, `234` = 234L, `235` = 235L, `237` = 237L, `238` = 238L, 
`239` = 239L, `241` = 241L, `242` = 242L, `243` = 243L, `244` = 244L, 
`245` = 245L, `247` = 247L, `248` = 248L, `249` = 249L, `250` = 250L, 
`252` = 252L, `253` = 253L, `254` = 254L, `255` = 255L, `257` = 257L, 
`258` = 258L, `259` = 259L, `260` = 260L, `262` = 262L, `263` = 263L, 
`264` = 264L, `265` = 265L, `267` = 267L, `268` = 268L, `269` = 269L, 
`270` = 270L, `272` = 272L, `273` = 273L, `274` = 274L, `275` = 275L, 
`277` = 277L, `278` = 278L, `279` = 279L, `280` = 280L, `282` = 282L, 
`283` = 283L, `284` = 284L, `285` = 285L, `287` = 287L, `288` = 288L, 
`289` = 289L, `290` = 290L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, `294` = 294L, 
`295` = 295L, `297` = 297L, `298` = 298L, `299` = 299L, `301` = 301L, 
`302` = 302L, `303` = 303L, `304` = 304L, `305` = 305L, `307` = 307L, 
`308` = 308L, `309` = 309L, `310` = 310L, `312` = 312L, `313` = 313L, 
`314` = 314L, `315` = 315L, `317` = 317L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, 
`320` = 320L, `322` = 322L, `323` = 323L, `324` = 324L, `325` = 325L, 
`327` = 327L, `328` = 328L, `329` = 329L, `330` = 330L, `332` = 332L, 
`333` = 333L, `334` = 334L, `335` = 335L, `337` = 337L, `338` = 338L, 
`339` = 339L, `340` = 340L, `342` = 342L, `343` = 343L, `344` = 344L, 
`345` = 345L, `347` = 347L, `348` = 348L, `349` = 349L, `350` = 350L, 
`352` = 352L, `353` = 353L, `354` = 354L, `355` = 355L, `357` = 357L, 
`358` = 358L, `359` = 359L, `361` = 361L, `362` = 362L, `363` = 363L, 
`364` = 364L, `365` = 365L, `367` = 367L, `368` = 368L, `369` = 369L, 
`370` = 370L, `372` = 372L, `373` = 373L, `374` = 374L, `375` = 375L, 
`377` = 377L, `378` = 378L, `379` = 379L, `380` = 380L, `382` = 382L, 
`383` = 383L, `384` = 384L, `385` = 385L, `387` = 387L, `388` = 388L, 
`389` = 389L, `390` = 390L, `392` = 392L, `393` = 393L, `394` = 394L, 
`395` = 395L, `397` = 397L, `398` = 398L, `399` = 399L, `400` = 400L, 
`402` = 402L, `403` = 403L, `404` = 404L, `405` = 405L, `407` = 407L, 
`408` = 408L, `409` = 409L, `410` = 410L, `412` = 412L, `413` = 413L, 
`414` = 414L, `415` = 415L, `417` = 417L, `418` = 418L, `419` = 419L, 
`421` = 421L, `422` = 422L, `423` = 423L, `424` = 424L, `425` = 425L, 
`427` = 427L, `428` = 428L, `429` = 429L, `430` = 430L, `432` = 432L, 
`433` = 433L, `434` = 434L, `435` = 435L, `437` = 437L, `438` = 438L, 
`439` = 439L, `440` = 440L, `442` = 442L, `443` = 443L, `444` = 444L, 
`445` = 445L, `447` = 447L, `448` = 448L, `449` = 449L, `450` = 450L, 
`452` = 452L, `453` = 453L, `454` = 454L, `455` = 455L, `457` = 457L, 
`458` = 458L, `459` = 459L, `460` = 460L, `462` = 462L, `463` = 463L, 
`464` = 464L, `465` = 465L, `467` = 467L, `468` = 468L, `469` = 469L, 
`470` = 470L, `472` = 472L, `473` = 473L, `474` = 474L, `475` = 475L, 
`477` = 477L, `478` = 478L, `479` = 479L), class = "omit"))



Please post some data. You can use the output of dput(ResponseData) or, to get fewer rows of data dput(head(ResponseData,30)), which will give the first 30 rows.

You need to call interaction() inside aes(), and also remove the quotes around the column names:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ResponseData, 
       aes(Time, Y, color = Treatment, shape = Genotype)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(Genotype, Treatment))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(19,24)) +
  labs(x = "Time (min)", y = "ETR") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,61), ylim = c(0,200)) +
  theme_bw()


In response to your comment, one way to achieve a 'break' in your lines is to add a new dummy variable to your df identifying Time <= 30.583333 and > 30.583333. You can then add this new variable to you existing interaction().
However, unless there is a sound methodological reason to do so, this risks visually misrepresenting your data. That's because adding a break in the lines implies each grouping is distinct. So while adding a break might result in a less cluttered plot, it's likely to be more graphically 'truthful' to maintain continuous lines. Something to think about anyway.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
ResponseData <- data.frame(
  Treatment = rep(c("Drought", "Heatdrought", "Control", "Heat"), each = 2),
  Time = rep(c(5.583333, 10.583333, 15.583333, 20.583333,
               25.583333, 30.583333, 35.583333, 40.583333,
               47.458333, 52.833333, 57.833333, 61.916667), each = 8),
  Genotype = rep(c("KU15", "KU2"), 48),
  Y = c(52, 54, 80, 110, 120, 121, 145, 148,
        55, 70, 99, 123, 130, 140, 166, 175,
        60, 77, 100, 124, 133, 147, 173, 178,
        68, 78, 100, 125, 140, 149, 174, 178,
        68, 79, 100, 125, 138, 150, 174, 178,
        75, 82, 101, 125, 139, 151, 173, 176,
        rep(seq(23, 26.5, .5), 6))
  ) |>
  arrange(Treatment, Genotype)
  
# Add dummy variable
ResponseData <- ResponseData |>
  mutate(grp_id = ifelse(Time <= 30.583333, 1, 2))

ggplot(ResponseData, 
       aes(Time, Y, color = Treatment, shape = Genotype)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(Genotype, Treatment, grp_id))) +  
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(19, 24)) +
  labs(x = "Time (min)", y = "ETR") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 61), ylim = c(0, 200)) +
  theme_bw()


This was so smooth, thank you, L Tyrone!
I am pondering which graph would best represent my measurements, and perhaps the break after the first 30 min would be good, i.e. a break between time = 30.583333 and 35.583333 for every group. Could you accommodat that? I'd appreciate it!
